# Не работает связь belongsTo() laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Подскажите, я ищу конкретную запись в laravel: `Information::where("url",$url)->first();` (связь belongsTo)
И пытаюсь таким образом обратиться к род. таблице:

```
dump($dataPage->user->email);
```

И в итоге выдает: **Trying to get property of non-object**

А когда ищу через: `Information::find($url)` (это если указываю url с цифр), то находит и все работает. 
Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать `Information::with('user')->first();`

А во избежание ошибки хелпер `optional();`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-optional

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading